# Installing communote on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, java

i am installing communote on ubuntu 10.04 server 64 (minimal install).

I am following the manual and accepting all standard settings but the server does not come up:

```
ad@communote:~$ tar -xzf Communote-linux-x64.tar.gz 
ad@communote:~$ cd Communote-1.1.4/
ad@communote:~/Communote-1.1.4$ sudo ./setup.sh 

... java licence ...

Do you agree to the above license terms? [yes or no]
                    yes

Please specify a name for Gruppe (communote): 

Please specify a name for Gruppe (communote): 

Please specify a name for User (communote): 
TOMCAT_USER=communote

Please specify a name for Verzeichnis (/opt/communote): 
Parameter= Verzeichnis /opt/communote

Please specify a name for Data_dir (/opt/communote/data): 
Parameter= Data_dir /opt/communote/data

Please specify a port the application should use [8080]: 

The port 8080 will be used.
Creating group: communote 
Creating user: communote 

Copying Java...tar xvfz files/32/jre-1.6.0_18-linux-x86.tar.gz /opt/communote/jre-1.6.0_18 Done.

Copying Communote... Done.
Preparing Communote...Done.
Starting Communote...
Done.
You should visit http://localhost:8080/ now to finish the installation. 

If your server wasn't started automatically, you should try to start it manually using:
   sudo su communote <Enter>
   /opt/communote/communote/bin/startup.sh <Enter>

ad@communote:~/Communote-1.1.4$ 

ad@communote:~/Communote-1.1.4$ sudo su communote
communote@communote:/home/ad/Communote-1.1.4$ /opt/communote/communote/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/communote/communote
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/communote/communote
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/communote/communote/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/communote/jre-1.6.0_18
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/communote/communote/bin/bootstrap.jar
communote@communote:/home/ad/Communote-1.1.4$ 

communote@communote:/home/ad/Communote-1.1.4$ exit
exit
ad@communote:~/Communote-1.1.4$ sudo ps aux|grep communote
ad        2122  0.0  0.1   7628   924 pts/0    S+   13:52   0:00 grep --color=auto communote
ad@communote:~/Communote-1.1.4$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
ad@communote:~/Communote-1.1.4$
```

So there is no process "communote" and no one listening on port 8080

Can you help?

*Edit*:

```
ad@communote:~/Communote-1.1.4$ sudo netstat -nltp
Aktive Internetverbindungen (Nur Server)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      971/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      584/smbd        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      971/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      584/smbd
```

*Edit2*:

This is the original startup script:

http://gist.github.com/615026

---

**Solution**:

I copied the 64 bit JRE from the installer manually to:

```
/opt/communote/jre-1.6.0_18
```

The dir was empty, now it has:

```
ad@communote:/opt/communote/jre-1.6.0_18$ ls
bin  COPYRIGHT  javaws  lib  LICENSE  man  plugin  README  THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt  Welcome.html
```

Now it starts as it should:

```
sudo su communote -c "/opt/communote/communote/bin/startup.sh"
```

Thank you fmysky!

**Edit:**

After some time I decided to reinstall communote on a 32 bit virtual machine. The JVM was sometimes slow on 64 bit.

Comment: What ports are you already using?   #sudo netstat -nltp

Comment: I added the info to the question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try 64-bit jre?

Comment: I found this in the logfile: /opt/communote/communote/bin/catalina.sh: 448: /opt/communote/jre-1.6.0_18/bin/java: not found

Comment: Great, you solved it. I copied 64 bit jre from the installer manually to the location from the logfiles.

Answer (score 1):

The setup.sh installer script tries to detect the architecture of your system. This is done by invoking 'uname -m' and checking whether it equals x86_64. This seems to fail on your Ubuntu installation. To fix this problem could you please tell us the output of that command.